# How do i get data based on the id in the array php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, search, filter

How do i get data based on the id in the array

```
array:60[
 3 => array:3[
  "id" => 4
  "name" => james
  "sex" => male
  ],
3 => array:3[
  "id" => 5
  "name" => mulan
  "sex" => female
  ]

]
```

I use laravel, and I use code like the following, but what is filtered is index array not based on id

```
 $response = Curl::to('127.0.0.2:8000/user/data')->get();
        $data = json_decode($response, true);    
        $outputData = $data["data"];
        dd($outputData[$request->id]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put that array in a Collection and use the `where` method to return the item based on `id`:

```
$collection = collect($thatArray);

$item = $collection->where('id', 5);
```

You could also key the collection by the 'id', then you can use `get`:

```
$collection = collect($thatArray)->keyBy('id');

$item = $collection->get(5);
```

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods - `where`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-where)

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods - `keyBy`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-keyby)

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods - `get`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-get)